# RequestBody Spring and AJAX post failed - invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I want to send value with ajax to spring java. in this case, I want send value with POST method but failed. before I use ajax, I use Swagger (plugin) for test post method run or not. when I use swagger, no problem for send value but I have problem in ajax.

in ajax:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8085/SpringNew/tesinsert";
var data, view = this;

            data = {
                "kodekasus" : 19,
                "nama" : "newnama",
                "isdelete" : null,
                "createdby" : "barunih",
                "createddate" : null,
                "updatedby" : "barunih",
                "updateddate" : null
            }

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : data,
            url : url,
            processData : false,
            contentType : 'application/*',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("success!");
            },
            error : function(e) {
            }
        });
```

spring controller:

```
@PostMapping(value={"/tesinsert"}, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody KasusEntity user) throws Exception {
    Map result = new HashMap();
    userService.insertTabel(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

the error show:

> jquery-dbg.js:9203 OPTIONS http://localhost:8085/SpringNew/tesinsert
>   403 (Forbidden) XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8085/SpringNew/tesinsert. Response for preflight has
>   invalid HTTP status code 403

how to fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: *consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE* `data` doesn't look like it is JSON to me

Comment: It's caused by Spring security, check the link provided in the previous comment.

Comment: before I change to consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, I use consumes="{application/json}" but show the same error